# Problem with boundary collision

Tags: java

**The problem:**
When the player hits the left boundary he stops (this is exactly what I want), when he hits the right boundary. He continues until his rectangle's left boundary meets with the right boundary.

**Outcome:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuJfIWZ_LL0&feature=youtu.be

**My Code**

```
public class Player extends GameObject{

BufferedImageLoader loader;
Texture tex = Game.getInstance();
BufferedImage image;
Animation playerWalkLeft;
private HealthBarManager healthBar;
private String username;
private int width;
private ManaBarManager manaBar;

public Player(float x, float y, ObjectID ID) {
    super(x, y, ID, null);
    loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    playerWalkLeft = new Animation(5,tex.player[10],tex.player[11],tex.player[12],tex.player[13],tex.player[14],tex.player[15],tex.player[17],tex.player[18]);

}

public void tick(LinkedList<GameObject> object) {

    setX(getX()+velX);
    setY(getY()+velY);
    playerWalkLeft.runAnimation();


}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());

    if(username != null) width = fm.stringWidth(username);
    if(username != null){
        g.drawString(username,(int) x-width/2+15,(int) y);
    }


    if(velX != 0){
        playerWalkLeft.drawAnimation(g, (int)x, (int)y);
    }else{
        g.drawImage(tex.player[16], (int)x, (int)y,  null);

    }


    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.drawRect((int)x,(int)y,33,48);
    g.drawRect(0,0,(int)Game.getWalkableBounds().getWidth(), (int)Game.getWalkableBounds().getHeight());


}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Image getCurrentImage() {
    return image;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    Rectangle gameBoundry = Game.getWalkableBounds();
    if(x >= gameBoundry.getMinX() && x <= gameBoundry.getMaxX()){
        this.x = x;
    }

}

public void setY(float y) { //IGNORE THE SetY please.
            this.y = y;
}

public float getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setHealthBar(HealthBarManager healthBar){
    this.healthBar = healthBar;
}

public HealthBarManager getHealthBar(){
    return healthBar;
}

public float getVelY() {
    return velY;
}

public void setVelX(float velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}

public void setVelY(float velY) {
    this.velY = velY;
}

public ObjectID getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setUsername(String playerName) {
    this.username = playerName;

}

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;

}

public void setManaBar(ManaBarManager manaBar) {
    this.manaBar = manaBar;

}

public ManaBarManager getManaBar(){
    return manaBar;
}

public int getLevel(){
    return 1;
}


public boolean isPlayerInsideBoundry(float x, float y){
    Rectangle boundry = Game.getWalkableBounds();


    if(boundry.contains(x,y)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

**What I've tried:**
- Using a method that checks if the game boundary contains player boundary rectangle. This gave me the same result as what the check statement in my setX did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either shift the right edge of `getWalkableBounds` to account for the geometry of the player (requires a new second function for the `renderableBounds`)

or you shrink the walkable bounds in the setX function

```
Rectangle gameBoundry = Game.getWalkableBounds();
gameBoundry.width-=PLAYER_WIDTH;
if(x >= gameBoundry.getMinX() && x <= gameBoundry.getMaxX()){
    this.x = x;
}
```

and do the same in `isPlayerInsideBoundry`

Comment: I don't seem to fathom your first solution, though I do get the second one, my player width is 33, so I did:

gameBoundry.width -= 33;

this made an debug output of: http://prntscr.com/3moto0
here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/rL5RZXJp

Btw, Game.getWalkableBounds() returns the size of the rectangle that the map is embedded in.

Comment: Oh, now I see why, it was because it wasn't the initial value. Thanks for your answer. I made it so that now it starts of as the initial value, so I minus 33 when I first create the image. Thanks!